# join tool does not extend the paths and join them where they intersect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

I think my problem has a very simple solution but I couldn't find it. My join tool can trim excess parts of a path but it does not extend the paths and join them where they intersect. What am I missing?

[image: doesn't extend]

[image: trims well]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the join tool only works when there is path data for it to connect.

[image]

Your ends are acting like to parallel lines | | there's no horizontal points for it to read to connect. You need a path that has some horizontal point for it to read like this |_ |

Comment: I've been playing with the Join tool since seeing this question. It's new to me. .. what a waste of development time it is :) Select the anchors.... command-J done. No too switching. :) Nice call on the answer though :)